# How Does Sum Function work?

Tags: matlab

for the following code:

```
A = 1:10
```

For `Sum(A)`   I get **55** which is the sum of the elements values.

But for the following I get:

```
A = 1:10
```

For `Sum(A<9)`  I get 8 which is the sum of elements that answer the condition (but not the sum of the values of the elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A<9` returns a binary vector with `1s` in the position that answer the condition and `0s` in the positions that do not. `sum(A<9)` thus sums a vector containing 8 `1s`, yielding 8, as expected. You should not be getting 9.

You want:

```
sum(A(A<9));
```

to get the sum of the values that meet the condition.

Comment: when writing sum(A(A<9)), (A<9) return a binary vector with 1s and 0s.
How does it know to sum the values only in where there are 1s.

Comment: Yea. When you index a matrix or vector `A` with a binary matrix/vector the same size as `A`, Matlab returns the values in the `A` that occur in the positions of the `1s`.